# I am trying to split the array into two parallel array

Tags: ruby

I have an array, and i need to split it into two, one after another scenario.

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I need to slip it into two like following

```
split1 = [2,4,6,8]
split2 = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

Comment: try to use : split1,split2 = number.partition(&:split1?)

Comment: Please edit your post, it is much confusing about the logic you want to built.

Comment: This is not a Rubyish code, thus I wouldn't add it as an answer.But you can copy it into your editor, and run it and try to understand it. If you do, then @sawa's answer will be clear to you. For your one `#partition` is a good choice although. `number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
split1,split2 = number.each_index.with_object(Array.new(2){ [] }) do |ind,ary|
  ind.even? ? ary[1] << number[ind] :  ary[0] << number[ind]
end
split1 # => [2, 4, 6, 8]
split2 # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

Answer (score 2):

A modification on Arup's answer:

```
split1, split2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].partition.with_index{|_, i| i.odd?}
split1 # => [2, 4, 6, 8]
split2 # => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

split1, split2 = %i[a b c d e].partition.with_index{|_, i| i.odd?}
split1 # => [:b, :d]
split2 # => [:a, :c, :e]
```

Comment: can you explain what happened here {|_, i| i.odd?}

Comment: @ArupRakshit It was good that you noticed `partition`. I could not come up with it.